# Change format of column in SSRS during export

Tags: reporting-services, string-formatting, export-to-excel

I have some date columns in SSRS that, when our internal users view/review data, need to be shown in the usual mm/dd/yyyy format.  The users also dump this report to Excel.  In the export, I need to convert the date to a string and format it yyyymmdd.

Is it possible to change the output format of a column only during an export?

EDIT: (based on comments below)

I love the phrase "almost exactly" :)

The other question mentioned below was asking WHY dates appear a certain way in Excel AFTER exporting but I wanted to change the format BEFORE or AS the export happened. My question had NOTHING to do with regional settings as the question referred to below mentions.

What I needed was for the date to show on the report (at the report server, on-screen) as 8/13/2013, let's say, but when I export it to Excel I needed a format of 20130813.

To be helpful to those that read this, adding a parameter to the report header, allowing the user to change a selection to run the report in two separate "modes" worked for me.

What I did was add a reportMode param, give it two values, say ModeA and ModeB.  I defaulted the param dropdown to ModeA.  In the date column, I simply checked for how the param was set and changed format of the date, through an expression prior to the user running the report.  This way the users can have ModeA to use when they are checking data but when they export this to excel for our external customers, who require the dates to be in the other format, they can choose ModeB, run the report again and then export.

Hope this helps somebody else.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSRS 2008 date formatting and exporting to excel confusion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358472/ssrs-2008-date-formatting-and-exporting-to-excel-confusion)

Comment: No it's not but I got it figured out.  Thanks.

Comment: Actually it almost exactly is!